# Is there any way to add axis labels on all four sides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  0.1, 0
1.10,  2,  2.2
1.10,  3,  2.1
1.10,  4,  1.5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, ymin=1, ymax=10]
\addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  0.1, 0
1.10,  2,  2.2
1.10,  3,  2.1
1.10,  4,  1.5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=1, ymax=10}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, tick pos=right, axis line style={draw=none}] \end{axis} %tick duplicates
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, tick pos=left]
\addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with tick labels on four sides]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. is there any way to make the 10^0 to 1?

Comment: Just this one label? -or all of them with the option: `log ticks with fixed point`