# How can i make the y values in 1 or 10 or 100 type rather than 10^n type?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  15, 0
1.10,  32,  32.2
1.10,  53,  52.1
1.10,  74,  91.5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=100, ymin=1, ymax=1000}
\begin{axis}[legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}}, 
             legend image post style={mark=*}, 
             ymode=log, ymin=1, ymax=1000,
             tick pos=right]
\end{axis}     
\begin{axis}[legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}},  
             legend image post style={mark=*}, 
             xlabel={X}, ylabel={Y}, 
             ymode=log, ymin=1, ymax=1000,
             tick pos=left]
\addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: User @hpekristiansen already provided you an answer to your new question, in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668343/5001) to your [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668342/5001): Add the option `log ticks with fixed point` after `tick pos=right` and `tick pos=left`, respectively. Remembers that options are separated by commas.

Comment: i don't know why but those solutions are not working for me